# Scala play json combinators for validating equality

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play 2.2.0 Reads for validating incoming request in my application.

I'm trying to implement a very simple thing with json API.
I have a json like this:

```
{
  "field1": "some value",
  "field2": "some another value"
}
```

I already have `Reads` that checks for other stuff like minimal length

```
case class SomeObject(field1: String, field2: String)
implicit val someObjectReads = (
  (__ \ "field1").read(minLength[String](3)) ~
  (__ \ "field2").read(minLength[String](3))
)(SomeObject)
```

I want to create a parser combinator that will match values of two fields and return `JsSuccess` if values are equal and otherwise `JsError` and combine it with existing `Reads`.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE: clarified the question and changed the code.

Comment: IMHO, this kind of validation should be done by the API client before sending the data to the API.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Yes, you're right (client actually does), but I want to implement both client and server side validation for this.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but if your API will be used by 3rd party developers, you can't enforce them to actually show users a "confirm password" field. They can just as well use the value from a single input field to populate both `password` and `passwordConfirm`. Anyway, it's obviously your choice in the end. I just wanted to present a different view of the problem.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Hm it's actually a good point. I think I'll remove this validation from the server in the future (api is not public yet so it's safe). Nevertheless, I'd love to see an example of parser combinator because I want to learn how to write such things in the future.

Comment: `Reads` is monadic, and some combination of `flatMap` and `verifying` should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: IMHO, either passwordConfirm may be deleted, or you should not check equality here. The json is valid (3 fields of type String min lenght 3).

Comment: Ok, I see I asked a question in the wrong way. What I'm asking about is how to build combinators, not about api design (btw thanks for advice guys!). I will update the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `filter` to do further validation on parsed values:

```
import play.api.data.validation._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

case class SomeObject(field1: String, field2: String)
implicit val someObjectReads = (
  (__ \ "field1").read(minLength[String](3)) ~
  (__ \ "field2").read(minLength[String](3))
)(SomeObject).filter(
  ValidationError("field1 and field2 must be equal")
) { someObject =>
  someObject.field1 == someObject.field2
}
```

If you want the error message to be listed against each field, then you'll have to use `flatMap`, eg:

```
implicit val someObjectReads = (
  (__ \ "field1").read(minLength[String](3)) ~
  (__ \ "field2").read(minLength[String](3))
)(SomeObject).flatMap { someObject =>
  Reads { _ =>
    if (someObject.field1 == someObject.field2) {
      JsSuccess(someObject)
    } else {
      JsError(Seq(
        JsPath("field1") -> Seq(ValidationError("field1 and field2 must be equal")),
        JsPath("field2") -> Seq(ValidationError("field1 and field2 must be equal"))
      ))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: James, thank you very much for the answer! Could you please elaborate on the format of the validation error type message? I'd like to get the error as something in format of like { "field1": "field1 and field2 must be equal", "field2": "field1 and field2 must be equal" } and your example gives something like List((,List(field1 and field2 must be equal))).

Comment: ValidationError is just a message key and some arguments, in the the above I haven't bothered to use a message key, but you could say ValidationError("validation.equals, "field1", "field2"), and define in your messages file "validation.equals={0} and {1} must be equal".

Comment: `ValidationError` was deprecated, instead `JsibValidationError` should be used. But very nice answer!