# Play Framework JSON automated mapping with custom validation

Tags: scala, play-json

Hi guys I'm new in the Scala world and I want to create a simple REST API using Play Framework. I'm working on JSON mappings to Case Classes, and I have maybe a stupid question.

I have a case class that represents a `UserDto` (it is used for user registration, and getting some basic info about the user)

```scala
case class UserDto(id: Option[Int], email: String, username: String, password: Option[String], confirmedPassword: Option[String])
```

So as it says in the Play Framework docs, there are multiple ways to map this to JSON, and I'm looking at the [automated mapping part](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated)

The way I've done it is

```scala
val userDtoWrites: OWrites[UserDto] = Json.writes[UserDto]
val userDtoReads: Reads[UserDto] = Json.reads[UserDto]
```

Now I want to add some validation to my UserDto, for example, to check if the Email is correct.

So my question is, is it somehow possible to create a Read for checking only the email field and add it to the automated generated Read?

I tried it with composeWith, but after running the second Read it only returns the email part.

```scala
val checkEmail: String = (JsPath \ "email").read[String](email)
val checkEmailJsString: JsString = checkEmail.map(s => JsString(s))
val newRead = userDtoReads.composeWith(checkEmailJsString))
```

For example, when a user wants to register:

```
{"email": "user@email.com", "username": "user","password": "password1234", "confirmedPassword": "password1234"}
```

That should map to:

```
UserDto(None, user@email.com, user, password1234, password1234)
```

if everything is correct. If the password does not match or the email has a bad format is should return 400 for example.

Comment: Why do you want to take this approach? You can just add a validation when creating the class: `case class UserDto (...) { checkemail(email) }`. This way it will be checked to all instances of this class, and not only to creation from json

Comment: I see your point, but my idea was to use this dto only as a part of http layer (meaning I will deserialize JSON into it, and I will copy data from a User model into it, which should be checked already). And I want to use Play's built-in email checking so I don't have to write my own regex.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, there is no automatic email check, but there is one as a part of Play's validation, here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Validation-with-Reads. And I want to combine it with the automated Read, but it appears it's not possible to combine two Reads that read different fields.

Comment: `val userDtoReads: Reads[UserDto] = Json.reads[UserDto]` and this one
`val checkEmail: String = (JsPath \ "email").read[String](email)`

Comment: Maybe adding a json of input, and the desired instance output will help answering better this question.

Comment: For example, when a user wants to register:
```{"email": "user@email.com", "username": "user","password": "password1234", "confirmedPassword": "password1234"}```
That should map to `UserDto(None, user@email.com, user, password1234, password1234` if everything is correct. If the password does not match or the email has a bad format is should return 400 for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have instances of `UserDto` which only has valid email then you should consider using Refined types (using e.g. https://github.com/avdv/play-json-refined to provide support for Play JSON).

```
import eu.timepit.refined._
import eu.timepit.refined.auto._
import eu.timepit.refined.api._
import play.api.libs.json._
import de.cbley.refined.play.json._

type EmailPattern = "^\S+@\S+\.\S+$"       // Scala 2.13 version
type EmailPattern = W.`"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$"`.T // before 2.13

type Email = String Refined string.MatchesRegex[EmailPattern]

case class UserDto(
  id: Option[Int],
  email: Email, // instead of plain String
  username: String,
  password: Option[String],
  confirmedPassword: Option[String]
)
object UserDto {
  implicit val userDtoWrites: OWrites[UserDto] = Json.writes[UserDto]
  implicit val userDtoReads: Reads[UserDto] = Json.reads[UserDto]
}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah, since Scala is a typed language I guess this makes the most sense. I will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use another library, you can implement your own `Reads[UserDto]`:

```scala
case class UserDto(id: Option[Int], email: String, username: String, password: Option[String], confirmedPassword: Option[String])

implicit val reads: Reads[UserDto] = (
  (__ \ "id").readNullable[Int] and
    (__ \ "email").read[String].filter(JsonValidationError("email is not valid"))(isValid) and
    (__ \ "username").read[String] and
    (__ \ "password").readNullable[String] and
    (__ \ "confirmedPassword").readNullable[String]
  ) (UserDto).filter(
  JsonValidationError("password and confirmedPassword must be equal")
) { userDto =>
  userDto.password == userDto.confirmedPassword
}
```

Then you can use it:

```scala
val successfulJsonString = """{"email": "user@email.com", "username": "user", "password": "password1234", "confirmedPassword": "password1234"}"""
val emailJsonString = """{"email": "user", "username": "user","password": "password1234", "confirmedPassword": "password1234"}"""
val passwordsJsonString = """{"email": "user@email.com", "username": "user","password": "password1234", "confirmedPassword": "1234"}"""

Json.parse(successfulJsonString).validate[UserDto].fold(println, println)
Json.parse(emailJsonString).validateOpt[UserDto].fold(println, println)
Json.parse(passwordsJsonString).validate[UserDto].fold(println, println)
```

And get the output:

```scala
UserDto(None,user@email.com,user,Some(password1234),Some(password1234))
List((/email,List(JsonValidationError(List(email is not valid),List()))))
List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(field1 and field2 must be equal),List()))))
```

I took references from [Scala play json combinators for validating equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21023428/2359227) and [how to add custom ValidationError in Json Reads in PlayFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44255681/2359227) to construct that solution.

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/KkNfosBEQU2ek5axDGKsUA).

Comment: I think your answer is not useful to the OP because they specifically asked about automated generation, they are aware of manually rolled codecs.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, it might be that you are right. But as I understand it the OP wants to have extra validations on top of the json validity. As shown in the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65616691/play-framework-json-automated-mapping-with-custom-validation/65674017?noredirect=1#comment116110416_65616691